# Getting active channels of a user in asterisk-java

Tags: java, asterisk

Is there a way to get all currently active channels of an IAX useraccount with asterisk-java?

Thanks
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the only way is to iterate through all channels and find the ones which belong to a specific user. It's neither extraordinarily nice, nor blazingly fast, but at least it works.